# wordpress php issue echoing html elements to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm having a nightmare with wordpress and PHP as I'm not great with either.

I'm trying to dynamically generate an options menu and I'm using the following lib:

http://loudev.com/

But, the output to the page appears as plain text values of the array I've pulled from my database (this is returned from the getB2BCountSelection(); function)

I've got the lib referenced in my header for the css and js file and jquery referenced etc.

so far as I can tell its simply that my HTML tags are not being written to the page DOM.

Here is an example of the output:

> select alldeselect all Abattoir Machinery and Equipment Abattoirs
>   Abrasive Products - Production Of Abrasive Products - Wholesale &
>   Supply Access Equipment Accident Administration & Management Services
>   Accommodation

Any ideas ?

EDIT: I'm running the below PHP and still getting the above issues and non tagged output.

```
[php]
$row = getB2BCountSelection();
$pages = count($row);
echo '<select id="public-methods" multiple="multiple">';
echo '<a href="#" id="select-all">select all</a>';
echo '<a href="#" id="deselect-all">deselect all</a>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$row[$i][0]."'>".$row[$i][0]."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
[/php]
```

Comment: You're echoing `<li>` inside your `<select>`

Comment: Thankyou! I've edited my post however it is still not rendering the content within html tags on my page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're NESTING two selects, producing the following (formatted) html:

```
<select>
   <a>....</a>
   <a>....</a>
   <select>
```

Both of your `<select>` tags have the SAME `id`, which is illegal - a DOM element ID must be unique across the entire DOM. Beyond that, your HTML is basically invalid. A `<select>` should not contain ANYTHINg other than `<option>` or `<optgroup>` tags. `<a>` and `<li>` inside is not valid.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! 

I've altered my code however I am still getting the same non tagged output.

[php]
$row = getB2BCountSelection();
$pages = count($row);
echo '<select id="public-methods" multiple="multiple">';
echo '<a href="#" id="select-all">select all</a>';
echo '<a href="#" id="deselect-all">deselect all</a>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$row[$i][0]."'>".$row[$i][0]."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
[/php]